# Termux: airmon-ng: Permission denied

Tags: termux

I want to run `airmon-ng`  but when I do it seems like the `airmon-ng` skript can't access other tools and it looks like this:

```
% sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 59: id: Permission denied
Unable to determine user id, permission errors may occur.
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 75: uname: Permission denied
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 171: ls: Permission denied

/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 1085: ls: Permission denied
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 1095: sed: Permission denied
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 1098: sort: Permission denied
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 982: grep: Permission denied
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 989: grep: Permission denied
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 1008: ps: Permission denied
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 1008: grep: Permission denied
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 1013: [: -gt: unexpected operator
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/airmon-ng: 1024: [: -gt: unexpected operator

PHY Interface   Driver      Chipset
```

In the first place I thought it is about the permissons of `airmon-ng` itself and I tried to change its permissions resulting in no changes of its behavior.
To me it seems like it can't be due to `id`'s permissions:

```
% ls -l id
lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a129 u0_a129 9 Jul  9 19:40 id -> coreutils
```

I already run `termux-setup-storage` and restarted. As this should not influence the issue it did not change anything as well.

Now I'm running out of clues and can't find similar issues. Got someone an idea?

Comment: From where did you get `sudo`? Try with Termux's `tsudo`.

Comment: I use the ```sudo``` from ```tsu/stable,now 8.5.1-2 all [installed]```. Can't find the command/package you mentioned, so I guess you ment ```tsu```?

Comment: `tsu`, `sudo`, `tsudo` etc. in Termux are not actual binaries but shell script wrappers around actual `su` binary provided by rooting solution like Magisk. You don't need to use any of the wrappers. Pass your command directly to `su -c`. But you obviously need to preserve Termux envitonment, in particular `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for Termux packages to work.